# Same type in different ocaml module doesn't match

Tags: types, module, ocaml

I'm sorry about this looking like a "trivia" question, but this is the most minimal example I could come up with:

```ml
module type Foo = sig
  type 'a t

  val foo : 'a -> 'a t
end

module Foo : Foo = struct
  type 'a t = T of 'a

  let foo x = T x
end

(* Rewrap foo, add one function *)
module type Bar = sig
  include Foo

  val bar : int -> int t
end

module Bar : Bar = struct
  include Foo

  let bar n = foo (n + 1)
end

(* Specialization of Baz for integers *)
module type Baz = sig
  type t
  val bar : int -> t
end

module Baz : Baz = struct
  type t = int Foo.t
  let bar = Bar.bar
end
```

In this example `Foo.t` and `Bar.t` are the exact same type. So therefore `int Foo.t` is the same as `int Bar.t`.

However, I get the following compilation error:

```
File "example.ml", lines 31-34, characters 19-3:
31 | ...................struct
32 |   type t = int Foo.t
33 |   let bar = Bar.bar
34 | end
Error: Signature mismatch:
       Modules do not match:
         sig type t = int Foo.t val bar : int -> int Bar.t end
       is not included in
         Baz
       Values do not match:
         val bar : int -> int Bar.t
       is not included in
         val bar : int -> t
       File "example.ml", line 28, characters 2-20: Expected declaration
       File "example.ml", line 33, characters 6-9: Actual declaration
```

if I replace `type t = int Foo.t` but `type t = int Bar.t`, suddenly the compilation match. In my original code, I have a lot of things that depends on both types. In my example, that would be this, which never compiles:

```ml
module type Baz = sig
  type t
  val foo : int -> t
  val bar : int -> t
end

module Baz : Baz = struct
  type t = int Foo.t
  let foo n = Foo.foo n
  let bar = Bar.bar
end
```

How can I tell the compile that `Foo.t` and `Bar.t` are the same, without making them "publicly visible"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example `Foo.t` and `Bar.t` are totally unrelated types for the point of view of the typechecker. Indeed, when you write

```
module Bar: Bar
```

you are constraining the type of the module `Bar` to be exactly `Bar.t`. And in the module type `Bar`, `Bar.t` is an abstract type without any known relationship with any other types.

If you want to keep the information that `Bar.t` is the same as `Foo.t`, you need to add back this information in the module type constraint:

```
module Bar : Bar with type 'a t = 'a Foo.t
```

In general, when you start writing module types in OCaml, it is better to start from the module types inferred by the type checker, and only remove information parsimoniously. Otherwise people often constrain modules with totally opaque module types that remove so much information from modules that they make the module useless.

For instance, with your simplified definition,

```
module type Foo = sig
  type 'a t
  val foo : 'a -> 'a t
end

module Foo : Foo = struct
  type 'a t = T of 'a
  let foo x = T x
end
```

The module `Foo` is mostly useless, because you have a black box type constructor `Foo.t` for which you can only create values of this type, but never destruct or consume them.

Comment: Can you expand on “better to start from the module types inferred by the type-checker?” For instance, what concrete changes would you suggest for that last code-snippet that implement your suggestion? (=

Comment: If you remove the `: Foo` annotation the typechecker will infer the most generic module type for the module: `module type Foo = sig type 'a t = T of 'a val foo: 'a -> 'a t end`. If you start from this module type, you can ask yourself what information can I remove from this signature. In this case, the answer is nothing. May I suggest you to ask a separate question if you wish for a more exhaustive question on when it is meaningful to abstract a type in a module type?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were talking about some process/idiom using some special compiler-flag, not simply omitting the type-constraint. My bad!